# VSFTPD server, free hosting?/ What next?

Tags: networking, ftp, vsftpd

I've been trying to host a ftp server from vpftpd and ufw. I've setup a dynamic DNS,  configured vpftpd from the conf file, which i can ping and run from my notebook and my android phone via termux. I've also setup a subdomain, I cant ping the sub domain but that's fine, since I can connect to it from a browser, only issues, I have a friend in a different country, when they go to my subdomain it redirects to my dynamic DNS but then states that it couldn't connect, any thing I should do?

Dynamic Dns: superbftp.hopto.org
Subdomain: superbftp.chickenkiller.com

P.S: Yes I have portforwared the ports that vsftpd running on, (port 21) things are a bit confusing since I'm using the ISP-provided router, which is a Bell Hub 2000

Comment: If you can connect properly on your LAN, then you have conclusively demonstrated that your Ubuntu server works. If you can connect properly across the internet in your country, then you have demonstrated conclusively that your router and DDNS are configured properly. and that your ISP allows inbound connections. If your friend still cannot connect, then it's a national-policy or ISP problem or some other issue at their end.

Comment: Thanks for the responce idk about it being a national-policy since she lives in the US of A but a provider issue makes sence, and its running though wifi since my router is in the basement and my notebook doesnt support ehternet or USB C.

Answer (score 2):

A few things...

- FTP is *woefully* insecure. Passwords passed in plaintext, no transfer encryption, etc. Any MitM will see all traffic. Strongly suggest using SFTP.
- Many browsers have stopped supporting FTP access. Chrome has dropped it already from its newer releases, and Firefox looks to be heading in the same direction. It might not be a network issue.
- That said, your hostname does not resolve here.

  ```
  $ ping superbftp.hopto.org
  ping: superbftp.hopto.org: Name or service not known
  ```

  I don't always expect a ping to get through but I do expect a host resolution.
  So not a port problem, a DNS problem.

Comment: weird, ping works fine from my notebook and my android, https://postimg.cc/QFW1jnQg thats a link to a screenshot, and ill look into sftp, thx for the help

Comment: okay so what happened was my laptop died and the ftp server completely corrupted its self, took a while to set back up but is running perfectly. idk what the issue is for my friend, prob latency since we live far apart and my network only hits 768KiB/s over wifi but ill see if my school wifi can connect to it or not. But i dont even know if they allow ftp connections, guess imma find out.